# facebook authentication doesnot redirect the same parameters

Tags: facebook

I try to authentication facebook. when it redirect it doesnot return the same parameters . some time it return

http://localhost/2/artist/?auth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F2%2Fartist%2Ffacebook.aspx%3Fartistid%3Dxxxx%26page%3D15664546%26isexisting%3Dfalse%26act%3Dadd%26step%3D1%26site%3Dfbevent

but mostly time it return

h`ttp://localhost/2/artist/?installed=1&next=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F2%2Fartist%facebook.aspx%3Fartistid%3Dxxxx%26page%3Dsdfasdf%2Bsdf%2Bsa%26isexisting%3Dfalse%26act%3Dadd%26step%3D1%26site%3Dfbevent&session={%22session_key%22%3A%222.cQWUqNcffzsWReDAcctOmA__.3600.1281524400-100000327994753%22%2C%22uid%22%3A100000327994753%2C%22expires%22%3A1281524400%2C%22secret%22%3A%22xOodxtnGGNMIK0F4Zq_sCw__%22%2C%22sig%22%3A%223eb5b89dd11e3b42d46587921ebecc52%22}`

why it return the different parameters??

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify your `localhost` urls to facebook. You need to upload your app to some server and use those urls instead.